# dojo1.8 unable to display BorderContainer and ConatentPane in JsFiddle

Tags: dojo

Hi I am unable to display BorderContainer and ContentPane in jsFiddle though I am able to display in Firefox browser. So what am I missing  in jsfiddle?

Here's my [work](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/kqNkX/31/) in jsfiddle

```
<div id="main_bContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar'">
<div class="cP_Left" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">ContentPane A</div>
<div class="cP_Right" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
data-dojo-props="region:'right'">ContentPane B</div></div>

require(["dojo/ready",
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/domReady!"], function (ready, declare, domConstruct, _WidgetBase, dom, on, parser) {
ready(function ()
parser.parse(); // check out more!

}); 
});
```

Clement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a couple of things:

1. A wrapping `<body class="soria">` tag around your dom
2. The css link to the soria theme was wrong
3. some missing brackets.

I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSG4S/).

dom:

```
<body class="soria">
    <div id="main_bContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
    data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar'">
        <div class="cP_Left" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">ContentPane A</div>
        <div class="cP_Right" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region:'right'">ContentPane B</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

code:

```
require(["dojo/ready",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (ready, declare, domConstruct, _WidgetBase, dom, on, parser) {
    ready(function () {
        parser.parse(); // check out more!
    });
});
```